# iPod touch calendar - all of my events AM and PM are switched

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization, ical

So I recently got an iPod touch and synced it with my computer. I set it up to sync with iCal. Unfortunately, on my iPod, all of my events are switched from AM to PM and vice versa. Or at least they are moved 12 hours forward/backward.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it? I'm trying to avoid wiping it clean, but if that's the only option, I will, because I really want to have iCal on my device.

Comment: Check you are working from the same timezone, and that your timezone support setting is configured or not.  Adding as a comment as it's just a hunch, not a definitive answer, but I'll happily make is an answer if it works :)

Comment: Yeah I checked that, and they were both in the same timezone. I actually fixed the problem just by updating to iOS 5. Thanks for your comment tho.